# iPhone app won't work on iPhone 3GS with iOS 4.3

Tags: ios, iphone, actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I was very successful in creating android apps with FlashDevelop 4.7. However, apple makes me troubles, as expected. I have created everything on apple developer site, mobileprovision file for app, .p12 file etc. IPA file has been compiled successfully. App has been installed successfully. But just won't run. After clicking icon, default.png displays for maybe second, maybe less, and just disappears. In app I have used nothing, just simple text displaying on the stage...

I don't know is the problem phone model (3GS 32 gb), or iOS (4.3.3) or cause OS is jailbreaked... It is just driving me nuts... Nothing helps... restarting iphone, uninstalling, installing.. nothing.. just default.png image and then quits.

When I compile same code with same mobileprovision and p12 file with flash CS6, code "works", but just blank page displayed after default loading image.

Summary Note: I have tested phone with very simple app... From CS6 - works, from FlashDevelop - no... Regular APP (works on android) from CS6 - works only default image, then blank page, from FlashDevelop - nothing...

I would appreciate any idea.

Comment: Couple comments: 1) Developing on a jailbroken phone leads to issues, and 2) I would not worry about developing for anything prior to iOS 7 (or maybe 6) at this point.

Comment: What's your ios target version?

Comment: It is 4.3 as a target. If I compile with higher version, won't install. I suspect in AIR 16 they are deprecating old iOS versions...